# Remove lines from one-dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to remove a whole few lines and separate a data sheet from a URL to fix what I need to print.
What do I need to use?

So far, I have this:

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        //String trimStr = line.trim();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " , ");
        int numberOfTokens = tokenizer.countTokens();
        String[] splitArr = new String[numberOfTokens];
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfTokens; i++)
            splitArr[i]=tokenizer.nextToken();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitArr));
```

I have a whole data list from a URL. How do I remove like 10 lines out of 20 so that is not shown in the output.

Input is the URL site in print view.
Expected Output is:

STATION:   DENVER, CO
MONTH:     JUNE
YEAR:      2012

Day    Min <----(Minimum temperature)

1      59

2      51

3      34

4      26

5      28

6      34

7      42

8      31

9      31

10     37

11     38
 etc......

Comment: what is the issue and where u stuck ?

Comment: I am good at displaying the URL data, then I don't know how to remove the parts I don't need visible for my output. How do I remove the lines and data I don't need. Above is a part of my working code to display URL.

Comment: sry but i m unable to understand the problem.What i understand,you have list and you want to extract only particular string from the list.Can you please explain input and expected output

Comment: I withdraw my thought

Comment: How is your data sorted? What elements do you want to extract? You only want temperatures for the first 10 days? Or maybe you wanted the 10 coldest days in a month? You should specify your problem better, else the answer can range from "keep a counter and break out of the loop when it hits 10" all the way to "build a `NavigableMap`" or even "use Guava".

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not as easily mutable as "real" collections in Java, so you should convert your split result to a `List<String>` and remove the unnecessary elements.